# What to use to replace the subquery in the SQL Server IN predicate

Tags: sql-server, predicate

Usually we have a subquery for the IN predicate. But I like to store the result from a subquery and use it in serveral IN predicates. I tried a temporary table but got an error - "Error 137: Must declare the scalar variable @xxx".

Say I have a book table Books:

```
ISBN | Title | Price | InStock(true/false)

DECLARE @SoldBooks TABLE (ISBN int)
INSERT INTO @SoldBooks(ISBN) SELECT DISTINCT ISBN FROM Books WHERE InStock = 0
SELECT Title FROM Books WHERE ISBN IN @SoldBooks
```

I am just using this script as an example to illustrate my issue. Please don't tell me there are better ways to get titles. Obviously the following code works,

```
SELECT Title FROM Books WHERE ISBN IN (SELECT DISTINCT ISBN FROM Books WHERE InStock = 0)
```

But I really like to find a way store the subquery. Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a table variable just like you describe:

```
DECLARE @SoldBooks TABLE (ISBN int)
INSERT INTO @SoldBooks(ISBN) 
SELECT DISTINCT ISBN 
FROM Books 
WHERE InStock = 0
```

Then you have to treat the table variable like a normal table:

```
SELECT Title 
FROM Books 
WHERE ISBN IN (SELECT ISBN FROM @SoldBooks)
```

Comment: ...though, as mentioned by @Joel, you're better off using a join, e.g. `SELECT bo.Title FROM Books bo INNER JOIN @SoldBooks sb ON sb.ISBN = bo.ISBN`

Comment: My main goal is to move logic to one place instead of duplicating in several IN predicates. Right now table variable is still my preferable solution. Thank you, Giorgos.

Answer (score 2):

Use a common table expression:

```
WITH ExpressionName As (
   Your Subquery goes here
)
select * from someTable1 t1
inner join someTable2 t2 ON ...
where t1.SomeValue IN (select * from ExpressionName)
  and t2.SomeValue IN (select * from ExpressionName)
```

Additionally, if you're doing this often, it's typically **much** better to use a `JOIN` for these situations:

```
WITH ExpressionName As (
   Your Subquery goes here
)
select * 
from tableTable
inner join someExpression ON ....
```

Finally, if by *"several IN predicates"* you mean more to re-use this same expression across different queries and reports instead of within the same query, you should create a **view:**

```
CreateView SoldBooks As
   SELECT DISTINCT ISBN 
   FROM Books 
   WHERE InStock = 0
```

And now you can use this view in `SELECT` situations as if it were a table. The same advice about `JOIN` vs `IN()` still applies.

Comment: Joel, thank you very much for showing so many examples. I did think about using CTE and join. But I didn't want to change the script structure too much so that everything had to retest.